# Is it possible to use 捷然 for a girl's name?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to choose a name for my baby girl and am wondering if i can use 2 words: 捷然 for middle and given name ?

Answer (score 1):

捷然 sounds fine to me. It is gender-neutral though, but no one says girls' names must be girlish.

You might also want to note that due to name ordering conventions in Chinese, usually we do not consider names with multiple characters as middle + given names; even though for some people, one of those characters does serve the purpose of a middle name (but it is not always the one in the middle either).

Answer (score 0):

Since the name is for a girl, I would suggest **婕然** instead of 捷然, unless you have attached a story or meaning to the latter.

- 婕 - handsome. (婕妤 - the official name of the female officer in the Han Dynasty)
- 然 is a sex-neutral word with many good meanings such as certainly, pledge, promise, understand, agree, fit, ... (the most associated words - 自然, 天然...)

Another suggestion will be "**潔然**", 取義於"簡**潔**自**然**".

Comment: agree,  婕然 instead of 捷然. don't use 捷然 as a girl name